# Stored Procedure Null Value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am working on an assignment and the basic function of this stored procedure is for the user to enter the City name and return the name of the employees and customers from that particular city. Where I am having trouble is that when I run the program it is supplying duplicate names instead of a null value in either column. I am also sure there is a better way to join these two tables together rather than one long join string but I am drawing a blank.

```
Create Proc DPCityContacts
 @City Varchar(20)
as
Begin

Select Distinct FirstName+', '+LastName as Employee, CustFirstName+', '+CustLastName as      Customer
into #tmp
from Employee E Join Packingslip PS on E.EmployeeID = PS.EmployeeID 
Join ShippedItem SI on SI.PackageNumber = PS.PackageNumber Join CustOrder 
CO on CO.OrderID = SI.OrderID Join Customer C on C.CustomerID = CO.CustomerID
Where @City = C.City  and @City = E.City and ReleaseDate is null 
Group by FirstName

if exists (select 1 from #tmp)
begin
select *
from #tmp;
end
else 
Print '“No Employees or Customers in the city of '+ @City
end
```

Comment: `If you enter a city name and want the employees and customers from that city`, then why do you join customer orders and shippeditems?  What do orders have to do with the city they are from? All you need is Employee and Customer tables.

Comment: Yes you are right but if i make two separate select statements it creates two windows and the error message no longer shows up. so i joined the employee table through shippeditems packingslips etc. to have all the results in one window.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want, but I am not sure as I cannot test. 
First of all I don't want all these joins as City is in the same table as employee and customer. 
And in all cases you want a UNION between the select on customer and the select on employee. You can't join these 2 tables together or you'll get weird results.

```
Select CONCAT(FirstName, ', ', LastName) AS Name, 'EMPLOYEE' AS type
INTO #tmp
FROM Employee
WHERE @City = City and ReleaseDate is null 
UNION
SELECT  CONCAT(CustFirstName, ', ', CustLastName) AS Name, 'CUSTOMER' AS type FROM
Customer 
INTO #tmp
WHERE @City = City and ReleaseDate is null
```

Comment: No i tried using a Union but it combines the results into a single column i need at lest two columns to identify whether they are employee or Customer

Comment: @user3380392 updated my answer to add an employee/customer type column to the result, you have to test if the query works, I didn't test it but I am sure this is your way to go.